# How to hardcode a text file into iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsbundle

Currently using:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
```

This only works however after I manually add the file into the application bundle.

I can use the documents directory but that's even worse.

After resetting the sim, the file goes away. How do I get it to stay?

How would I write out the file from somewhere to there? Like from a file in source? I don't want to alloc a several megabyte NSString object.

Comment: If you want the file to be part of the bundle you need to tell Xcode to put it in the bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to Lyle42 on freenode irc (#iphonedev):

I wasn't aware this field even existed. By adding any file into the copy files build phase (under build phases), they persist across builds.

Then this code:

```
NSString *_filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"txt"];

NSLog(@"%@",_filePath);

NSData *_binary = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:_filePath];  

NSString *_fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_binary encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Works just great. (loads contents of file into an NSString).

[image: copy files build phase]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get your path for the file

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file_name];
```

you can get the file from your app bundle using

```
NSString *pathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:file_name];
```

Comment: The first solution will only work if the file is in the documents directory—otherwise, it's no more effective than trying to access a file in the bundle that isn't in the bundle. The second solution is equivalent to the questioner's code, but the questioner's version is shorter, simpler, and more robust.

Comment: This is good code, but it should not be used in the context set by the question

Answer (score 0):

> I can use the documents directory but that's even worse.

Not really.  The documents directory is persistent, and the recommended directory for essential documents created by your application.  In addition, it's backed up by iTunes, and can be specified for iCloud backup.  The app bundle just can't compete with that!

> After resetting the sim, the file goes away. How do I get it to stay?

You can't, once the simulator has been "reset" (and I mean a hard wipe of all data and apps), nothing is saved.  In between test builds, however, data copied out of the app bundle should survive unless you're storing things in `/tmp`.  In addition, objects in the bundle are "refreshed" (recopied) in the build phase, meaning your resource isn't wiped out, merely reset to the one specified in your project.

> How would I write out the file from somewhere to there? Like from a
>   file in source? I don't want to alloc a several megabyte NSString
>   object.

To read the file into memory, it would have to turn into a "several megabyte NSString" eventually, but if you really want to add a little IO to your plans for a massive string object, have a look at `NSFileManager`.

Comment: Oh ok... my question is a little bit different though. I'm wondering how I can write the file to any of these in the first place so it's there to be read at a later point in time.

Comment: NSFileManager, bro.  It's so trivial to write a file to a dir, and the documentation is so good.

Comment: Right right but where would the data originate in the first place?

Comment: Drag a txt file into your Xcode project!  Or, better yet, define an NSString, and write it to a .txt file.

Comment: The answer was that I needed to add the text file to the copy file buildphases tab...